# How to use deadpool-postgres crate in binary and postgres crate in library?

Tags: postgresql, rust

I have a binary crate using deadpool-postgres for connection pooling and I have a library crate that uses postgres for connections. In the library crate, I need to pass a postgres `Client` object to a struct to execute queries. In the binary crate, I use deadpool-postgres to create a connection pool and use that pool to get the connection objects to run queries.
In library crate:

```
struct Data {
  client: postgres::Client
}
```

How do I pass a `Client` object from the binary crate to the library crate. I have tried:

```
let client = pool.get().await.unwrap();
let data = Data { client: client };
```

but the client variable contains a `Manager` object instead of a client. How do I get the `Client` object from the `Manager` object?

Comment: should be possible to use `*client` https://docs.rs/deadpool-postgres/0.9.0/deadpool_postgres/struct.ClientWrapper.html#impl-Deref

Comment: notice that deadpool is async and so use tokio version of postgres if you need a sync pool https://docs.rs/r2d2/0.8.9/r2d2/index.html